# Using a loop in plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, loops

Can someone give me an example on how to use a loop in plain JavaScript, where I have a starting number, lets say (var a = 5000;) and I want to add 5000 to it, to a maximum of 50000.
I have to write a simple interest loan program to run in Nodejs.

I need to modify the previous version of a program I wrote so it uses a loop to calculate the interest using different loan principles. The loan principal should start at 5000 and increase by 5000 each iteration of the loop. The loop should terminate when the loan principal exceeds 50000. Each pass of the loop, display the output as before but using the new loan principal. If
the interest in a given pass of the loops exceeds $200, display the following
warning message:“*** Warning *** You are paying an excessive amount of interest. Please consider a higher down payment!”

Here is my previous program:

```
var loanPricipal = 20;
var interestRate = 20;
var termOfLoan = 45;

var calcInterest = (loanPricipal * (interestRate * termOfLoan / 365));

var totals = ("");

var a = calcInterest;
    a /= Math.pow(10, -0);
    a = '$' + a.toFixed(2);

totals =
 (("Loan Principal: ") + loanPricipal + '\n' + '\n' + ("Interest Rate: ") + interestRate + '\n' + '\n'  + ("Term of Loan in Days: ") + termOfLoan + '\n' + '\n' + ("The Interest Charged is ") + a + '\n');


console.log(totals);
```

‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌‌

Answer (score 0, accepted):

enter code hereI'm not sure if I got it, However I'll try to help you. Is something like this that you need?

```js
var interestRate = 20;
var termOfLoan = 45;

for(var loanPricipal = 5000; loanPricipal <= 50000; loanPricipal += 5000) {

  var calcInterest = loanPricipal * (interestRate * termOfLoan / 365);
  var a = calcInterest;
    a /= Math.pow(10, -0);
    a = '$' + a.toFixed(2);

    var totals = (("Loan Principal: ") + loanPricipal + '\n' + '\n' + ("Interest Rate: ") + interestRate + '\n' + '\n'  + ("Term of Loan in Days: ") + termOfLoan + '\n' + '\n' + ("The Interest Charged is ") + a + '\n');

        console.log(totals);
      console.log("\n-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=")
    }
```

Comment: I tried that but is not giving me the multiple results that I need, I don't understand loops very well yet, that may be my problem.

Comment: Could I upload a .js file so you can see what I am looking at? I don't know if that is possible here.

Comment: Sure. I see that you are learning. If you could clarify your question as well. It would be nice.

Comment: Thanks. What I need to understand is, how do I tell the the loop what I want to do? I have 3 variables, (a) var principal = 5000 ,(b) var interest = 20%, and (c) var days = 45, I create another variable to calculate the interest, var calInterest = a *( b * c) / 365,  then I output principal, interest, days, and interest charged for the 45 days,

Comment: continuation... using a loop, I have do the same calculation, but this time the principal have to be increase by 5000 every time the loop passes up to 50k and the new output has to be displayed if the amount of interest charged is 200 or more a warning will be displayed

Comment: I want to know how to give the values to the loop in order to get multiple outputs of the same calculation, while increasing the principal by 5000 every time, up to 50k.